# get list from Tkinter text field, check for duplicates and remove any

Tags: python, tkinter, get, duplicates

I am trying to clean a text field of its duplicate items (each item is on a new line in the text field). My logic: call get() on the text field, insert into a list, and then run an admittedly slow series of nested loops to check for duplicates and then repopulate the text field.

Could someone please help evaluate my logic and tell me why this isn't working?

```
def checkDup(self):
                clean = []
                dirty = O1.get("1.0", END+'-1c').split("\n")       
                for i in dirty[1:]:
                        if i not in clean:
                                clean.append(i)
                                clean.append("\n")
                O1.delete("1.0", END)
                O1.insert(END, clean)
```

Comment: This is not a **minimal, complete and verifiable** example. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would have used the same logic with for loops for checking duplicates.. maybe there is something better out there to do that but for now at our level I think it's a good start.

reviewing your code:

```
for i in dirty[1:]:
```

Here why do you start after the first item in your list, does it need to be excluded? if so, you are deleting it anyways with:

```
01.delete('1.0', END)
```

You may need to change your code to **01.delete('2.0', END)** if you need to keep the first line.

```
if i not in clean:
    clean.append(i)
    clean.append('\n')
```

Here, you are creating a longer list with a bunch of newlines that are each considered a member of your list, interesting.. I messed up with this portion.. after testing I see your results are only half as weird as what I did.

last line: you are pushing your corrected list directly in your widget, which causes a weird result.

```
01.insert(END, clean)
```

Fix that one this way; **01.insert(END, ''.join(clean))** this will break your list into a string containing your previously inserted newlines, putting all the text in the right place.